# cannot access the row values of an object using javascript and ejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, ejs, embedded-javascript

I have an **ejs** file which looks like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
 <title>Google Maps Sensor  Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
      <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="pil"></p>
    <p id="rowc"></p>
 <script>
      function addZero(i) 
      { if (i < 10)
          { i = "0" + i;
            }
          return i;
      }
  var d = new Date(1382086394000);
  //var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var h = addZero(d.getHours());
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= h + ":" + m + ":" + s;       
  var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(jsresult) %>; 
  var count= <%- rowcount %>       

document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML=  myVar.rows[0].sensor;
document.getElementById("rowc").innerHTML=  count;
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

which gives me the output like below:

```
01:53:14

6

7
```

I am trying to get the values of sensors from myVar by performing an iteration instead of accessing by using

```
   myVar.row[0].sensor , myVar.rows[1].sensor and so on...
```

So I added something like this in between the above code

```
 .
 .
 .

 var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(jsresult) %>; 
  var count= <%- rowcount %>

  var arlene1= [];   
   for (var j=0; j<=count;j++)
   { arlene1[j] = myVar.rows[j].sensor ; 
   }  

 document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML=  myVar.rows[0].sensor;
document.getElementById("rowc").innerHTML=  count;

.
.
.
```

it now just throws a blank page without no output.

Can someone explain what is wrong over here??

I am basically trying to get the values of all 7 sensors into an array and then present them on the UI

The debugger console shows the error like below: [image]

Answer (score 0):

In the last block of code, you've assigned `rowcount` to the `count` variable, but in the for loop you're trying to access `rowcount`. `rowcount` is undefined when the JavaScript code is evaluated on the client. Try changing it to this:

```
var myVar = <%- JSON.stringify(jsresult) %>; 
var count= <%- rowcount %>; // 7

var arlene1= [];

// Iterate from 0 to 6
for (var j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
    arlene1[j] = myVar.rows[j].sensor; 
}  

document.getElementById("pil").innerHTML=  myVar.rows[0].sensor;
document.getElementById("rowc").innerHTML=  count;
```

Comment: i have tried that way too. i forgot to change the code here.
I still get a blank page even after giving count or making the loop run for 6 times instead of count

Comment: @MonicaThaneer: Check my edit - there was a syntax error in the `for` loop, too. You're using a comma rather than a semi-colon.

Comment: I get the time printed now. but still i do not get the 'pil' and 'rowc' values displayed.

Comment: if i remove the loop , the 'pil' and 'rowc' values are displayed. but i want fetch the values of sensor using a loop :-|

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding - I fell asleep! Try using the Google Chrome JavaScript console to see if you're getting any errors when you load the page. It's really handy in situations like this, when there's a pesky syntax error that isn't immediately obvious. Here is a good intro to using it: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: it says cannot read property sensor of undefined.
but why is that so .. when i use myVar.rows[0].sensor i dont get any error and when i say myVar.rows[j].sensor it throws an error.

Comment: I have added the console image in the question above

Comment: @MonicaThaneer: Try changing the for loop condition to `j < count`. I think, currently, `j` is incremented all the way up to 7, but `myVar.rows[6]` is the last element in the array. See my edited answer.